# Open a new activity for each list item clicked from webview

Tags: java, android, html, webview

I am loading html file from asset folder in a webview. There is an unordered list. I want to open a new activity when each list item is clicked. This is what I was trying so far. But it shows file not found error. I am attaching a picture of my desired scenario. Please have a look at that. It will help you understand my problem.[Wanted Scenario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Yt3U.jpg)

```
wv_topic_details = findViewById(R.id.wv_topic_details);

    wv_topic_details.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(TopicDetails.this, PrachinYug.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
    });

    wv_topic_details.loadUrl(file_path);

    webSettings = wv_topic_details.getSettings();
    webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true); //enable zoom facility
    webSettings.setDisplayZoomControls(false); //hide the zoom control switch
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
        android:name=".TopicDetails"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <data android:scheme="prachin_yug"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".PrachinYug"
        android:label="@string/prachin_yug"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <data android:scheme="prachin_yug"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
<activity
        android:name=".MadhyaYug"
        android:label="@string/madhya_yug"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <data android:scheme="madhya_yug"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

<activity
        android:name=".AdhunikYug"
        android:label="@string/adhunik_yug"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <data android:scheme="adhunik_yug"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

This is the html file. This file is in the TopicDetails class. I want to open PrachinYug, Madhyaug and AdhunikYug class when respective item is clicked in the list. The target classes are not webview. They are android listview.

```html
<p>
    আনুমানিক ....... করা যায়। যথা-
</p>
<ul>
    <li><a href="prachin_yug">প্রাচীন যুগ</a></li>
    <li><a href="madhya_yug">মধ্যযুগ</a></li>
    <li><a href="adhunik_yug">আধুনিক যুগ</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I have edited my question and added an image. Please look at that.

Comment: You mean to say that you wanted to open a activity on click of a link and inside that activity you want to load a  listview of some data.

Comment: No exactly, I already have those activities "A", " B" and "C" and they are opening perfectly from the main activity. Now I want to open those activity from a link on another activity ( in this case the "Intro" activity) which is a webview. It's kind of by passing you may think.

Comment: My solution is correct for that! Just use the URL by comparing it with the clicked one.

Comment: I think I understand what you are saying. But for  activity "A", " B" and "C" I have no url, there is no html file for them, they are android ListView. Which url should I use?

Comment: When list items in the main activity are clicked it fires an intent of "A.class" and so on. Think of a button click. Generally when we have a button, we set a onclick listener and fires intent to open a new activity. I want the links to act as the button in the intro activity.

Comment: Link mean "file:///android_asset/html/a.html"?

Comment: Link mean "file:///android_asset/html/a.html"?  No, I don't have this kind of html file for A, B, C activity. They are RelativeLayout having a ListView. As I told you I already have gates to open these in main activity. I have another activity which is a webview displaying intro.html file. There are these three words " A", "B" abd "C". I want when I touch those words they open the respective class. Is it possible

Comment: You mean to say that when listview is clicked then inside another activity webview page with specific link will load.

Comment: Yes, not only the links other contents are also there in the intro webview. Now when the links are clicked it should open the respective activity. If there were html file for those activity it would be easier, but there is none. Also there is only text no buttons in the webview. So I can't use onclick listener.

Comment: So you are able to open your webview

Comment: Yes. The intro webview and all the other classes "A", " B"...  are opening perfectly. I want to open "A", " B".... activity from the intro webview. So that if someone is in the intro webview, he can directly go to the activity "A", " B" and so on. Otherwise he has to go back to the main activity and the go to the respective activity.

Comment: So why below solution is not working.

Comment: url.equals("Your URL inside yourfile.html")- what url shall I use here. I told you I don't have any html file for activity "A", " B" and "C".

Comment: May be either of us not getting each others point. So if you provide me your no. (If you wish) I can talk to you. Thank you for your patience and time.

Comment: URL means your: prachin_yug and madhya_yug like that.

Answer (score 0):

**Main Activity:**

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WebView webview = findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/yourfile.html");
        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url{
                if (url.equals("Your URL inside yourfile.html")) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(this, YourActivity.class));
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout   
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview_contributors"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you @Sumit, but this is not my solution. because the target classes e.g. PrachinYug.class is not a webview. It is an  android ListView. Sorry, I forgot to say that.

Comment: Yes, i saw that. But not getting what I have to do